# I'd like to use vim on my work laptop, but my company does not allow us to install software. What are my options?

Tags: windows, vim

As the title says, I want to use vim but I'm not allowed to download or install software from the Internet.

I'm on Windows 7, and have access to the following pre-installed software:

- Chrome 37 (and extensions/apps/javascript are allowed)
- IE 11
- Office 2010 (and I can write my own macros)
- Powershell 2.0

I got really really excited when I found [vim.js](http://coolwanglu.github.io/vim.js/emterpreter/vim.html), (source available [here](https://github.com/coolwanglu/vim.js)), but it looks like you still have to run a binary for vim (not really sure what the point if you have to run the binary.

I mainly want it for text editing; I'm not writing code.

What are my options?

Comment: Are you allowed to use anything off of a USB, portable software?

Comment: http://portablegvim.sourceforge.net/

Comment: http://www.compileonline.com/online_vi_editor.php

Comment: http://gpl.internetconnection.net/vi/ "Now you can try out Vi and all its shortcut/macro goodness online with jsvi, a JavaScript-written clone of the basic Vi interface. It's obviously focused on code, carrying substitutions and spell checking for the most common languages, but it's a fun place to try out coding for newcomers, or for programmers to do a little quick hacking when they're away from their systems."

Comment: To those asking about running from a USB stick, no I can't do that (or AFAIK, I could get in trouble for running a binary application regardless of how I got it on there).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### What are my options?

If you can run applications from a USB Stick try [GVim Portable](http://portablegvim.sourceforge.net/):

> The GVim Portable Launcher allows you to run GVim from a removable drive whose letter changes as you move it to another computer. The program can be entirely self-contained on the drive and then used on any Microsoft Windows computer.

If you can run applications online, try:

- http://www.compileonline.com/online_vi_editor.php:

  > Online vi Editor  - You can compile and run, execute your source html related to Java, JSP, Cold Fusion, C, C++, Pascal, Fortran, PHP, Perl, Ruby and Python programs onnline using your browsers, iPhone, iPad or any other online device like smart TV using this virtual Linux / Unix  Server.
- http://gpl.internetconnection.net/vi/:

  > Now you can try out Vi and all its shortcut/macro goodness online with jsvi, a JavaScript-written clone of the basic Vi interface. It's obviously focused on code, carrying substitutions and spell checking for the most common languages, but it's a fun place to try out coding for newcomers, or for programmers to do a little quick hacking when they're away from their systems.

Both of the above online applications run on the latest Firefox, but I haven't performed any extensive testing.

Comment: The second one seems to be what I'm looking for; I was even able to run it locally (in chrome of course).  Now I just need to find a way to save to a given file.

Comment: @Jay "Download Files" button, top right of screen ;)